# Weird behaviour of hyperlinks in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have two columns of data in Excel and am trying to use openpyxl to format them.

The first column is a URL. I want to set the second column to be a hyperlink to the URL and then delete the first column. I am also setting the formatting of this column to look like a hyperlink - Underlined and blue color. I am using the following code. (The below code only has one line of data so that it is easier to understand)

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font

#Set Up Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'] = r'C:\Users'
ws['B1'] = 'Click To Open Users'
ws['C1'] = 'qwertyuiop'

#Format Cells
ws.cell(row=1,column=2).hyperlink = ws.cell(row=1,column=1).value
ws.cell(row=1,column=2).font = Font(color="0000EE", underline='single')

#Delete First column (The other columns should shift to the left)
ws.delete_cols(1)  


wb.save(r"C:\Test.xlsx")
```

However the result of this code is an excel sheet with a hyperlink in the **2nd** column! (The blue format and underline are in the 1st column as expected)

When I don't delete the 1st column everything works as expected so this is just a weird quirk that when I delete the first column the hyperlink doesn't move over.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I used version 2.6.1 and then upgraded to 3.0.3 and the same thing was happening.

Comment: [Edit] your question and show your `openpyxl` version.

Comment: I just confirmed the behaviour with `openpyxl 3.0.3` - it looks to me like a bug in `openpyxl`. Maybe someone here knows about a workaround, but you should probably just submit a bug report. If you don't delete the column, the behaviour is as expected, but if you do delete the column, the hyperlink still appears to be applied to column 2 (which now contains `'qwertyuiop'`) instead of having shifted over to column 1 with the link text.

Comment: Note that the behaviour also occurs if you save the sheet with the link it the correct position, reopen the sheet and modify it by deleting a column - the link doesn't shift with the column. And the same happens if you create the sheet manually (in Excel) and then delete a column before it - `openpyxl` consistently breaks hyperlinks when deleting a column to the left of them.

Comment: Thanks @Grismar bug reported here https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1429/hyperlink-doesnt-shift-with-column

Comment: Similar behavior with `openpyxl==3.0.5`. When deleting rows with `openpyxl` the hyperlink does not get deleted. It stays in place distorting the data. Same happens with when inserting rows. However, when deleting or inserting manually in the excel file, the hyperlink gets deleted or moves as well (shows the expected behavior)

Comment: As stated [here](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1429) developers do not consider it as an issue as "openpyxl is not a replacement for Excel so it does not keep track of stuff when you make changes such as adding or deleting rows or columns. You have to do this in your own code.". Thus they are not going to fix it. @ElkanaTheGreat you could post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developers do not consider it as an issue as "openpyxl is not a replacement for Excel so it does not keep track of stuff when you make changes such as adding or deleting rows or columns. You have to do this in your own code. We moved cell objects and they contain formatting but hyperlinks are distinct objects that refer to cells. We also generally don’t update formulae or charts."

Link here: https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1429