# Openpyxl don't move hyperlink location after delete_rows()

Tags: hyperlink, openpyxl, delete-row

I am trying to use openpyxl `delete_rows()` to delete a row from a spreadsheet. The content of the row is removed fine, and the value from the following rows are moved ahead. However,  the `hyperlink` of the following rows are not adjusted accordingly. This will cause `value` and `hyperlink` not consistent.

An example to duplicate this problem

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

destExcelName = 'd:\Temp\hello.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(destExcelName)
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'].value = 'Google'
ws['A1'].hyperlink = 'https://www.google.com'
ws['A1'].style = 'Hyperlink'

ws['A2'].value = 'Apple'
ws['A2'].hyperlink = 'https://www.apple.com/'
ws['A2'].style = 'Hyperlink'

ws['A3'].value = 'StackOverflow'
ws['A3'].hyperlink = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
ws['A3'].style = 'Hyperlink'

ws.delete_rows(2)
wb.save(destExcelName)
wb.close()
```

After delete row 2 (the `apple` line). `StackOverflow` line is moved ahead and become the new row 2. However, its hyperlink still remains on `A3`, and `A2` don't have a hyperlink value.

[image: Hyperlink in A3 not moved to A2]

Anything can be done to overcome this limitation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60659476/weird-behaviour-of-hyperlinks-in-openpyxl

Comment: After some investigation, I believe this is a bug on openpyxl and update my findings in [Issue 1318](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1318)